# Nagios plugin script not working as expected

Tags: bash, nagios

Below is the my script, in which i am using [jvmtop.sh](http://code.google.com/p/jvmtop/) script's output to store in respected variables and later for processing in nagios with graphs.

In client server bash, the script outputs as expected. but when i do Test check command in nagios, it seems ./jvmtop.sh doesn't store output in the variable. I am getting "CRITICAL - Process to monitor is not running!"

Let me know what i am missing..

```
get_vals() {
current=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/
cd $current           
OLDIFS=$IFS                
IFS='\n'         
tmp_output=$(./jvmtop.sh --once | grep $process)
IFS=$OLDIFS
    if [ -z "$tmp_output" ]
    then
        echo "CRITICAL - Process to monitor is not running!"
        exit $ST_CR
    fi
PID=`echo ${tmp_output} | awk '{print $1}'`
HPCUR=`echo ${tmp_output} | awk '{print $3}' | sed 's/.$//'`
HPMAX=`echo ${tmp_output} | awk '{print $4}' | sed 's/.$//'`
NHCUR=`echo ${tmp_output} | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/.$//'`
NHMAX=`echo ${tmp_output} | awk '{print $6}' | sed 's/.$//'`
CPU=`echo ${tmp_output} | awk '{print $7}' | sed 's/.$//' | cut -d . -f 1`
GC=`echo ${tmp_output} | awk '{print $8}' | sed 's/.$//' | cut -d . -f 1`
THREAD=`echo ${tmp_output} | awk '{print $11}'`
}
```

Comment: also try export JAVA_HOME={path to it} on the top of your own shell script so when nagios runs it - it can find it -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I think it may be due to the definition of jvmtop.sh on line 120, my suggestion would be to give the full path to the script....

```
tmp_output=$(./jvmtop.sh --once | grep $process)
```

to

```
tmp_output=$(/path/to/jvmtop.sh --once | grep $process)
```

If this does not help, try enabling debug and defining the debug level in your nagios.cfg:

```
debug_level=2048 
debug_file=/var/log/nagios_debug.log
```

Do turn this off once you have finished with it.

E2A:
One last thing would be after this line (120) to echo out the result of tmp output to a temp file and look at its output to see if it has really worked !

so echo $tmp_output > /tmp/observe.txt

since my my suspicion still is on this - I sent a comment above to also export out your java home since its either that it can't find this jvmtop.sh or if it can it don't know what $JAVA_HOME/bin/java is ...

Comment: Hi, I tried all of your steps. but seriously, it driving me nuts. It doesn't looks like nrpe daemon actually executing the subscript (jvmtop.sh) inside main script.  i get no output for tmp_output. Also googling doesn't show any info of how subscript can be used inside nagios plugin.

Comment: Doubt its anything to do with nrpe - its actually something missing for it not to be able to execute the jvmtop.sh  try sourcing or exporting your environment variables such as SHELL PATH etc in your main script, replace the other script call with a number that is successful see if that works - you could always look at putting the jvmtop.sh script as a function inside your main script -- but i still think there is something not available for it not to work this way

Comment: vahid, pls execuse me.. i made a mistake in setting PATH.  export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6xxx  in my MAIN script solved the issue.  Thanks for your valuable time in point it out.

Comment: No worries glad to have helped out - its all part of the learning curve and this way you learn best of all :)